# How do I delegate this constructor?

Tags: c++, object

For an c++ assignment I need to work with a Point class and with that Point class I need to make a Triangle class.

I used the following constructors for the Point class:

```
//constructor 1
Point() 
{
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}

//constructor 2
Point(double i, double j)
{ 
    x = i; 
    y = j;
}
```

My first constructor for the Triangle class is:

```
  Triangle()
    {
        a = Point();
        b = Point();
        c = Point();
    }
```

Now the next step is:

> Create a constructor that takes three Point arguments and initialises
> attributes a, b and c with the three arguments. Use constructor
> delegation for the initialisation of the attributes.

I read that you need you use constructor delegation in order to delegate work that is already done to the new constructor in order to prevent rewriting code.

```
  Triangle(Point a, Point b, Point c)
        {
         
        }
```

I'm a beginner and I find it really hard to make a new class with an already existing class.  Could I please get feedback on how I could delegate this constructor?

Tim

Comment: `Triangle(Point a_, Point b_, Point c_) : a(a_), b(b_), c(c_) : {}` should do the trick.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks for the reply, honestly I don't understand what is done. Could you maybe explain it? That would be helpful!

Comment: Here's a more detailed explanation of the syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a slightly refactored version of your code that reflects more modern C++ practice (since 2011):

```
struct Point {
    Point() = default;
    Point(double i, double j) : x(i), y(j) {}

    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;
};

struct Triangle {
    Triangle() = default;
    Triangle(Point i, Point j, Point k) : a(i), b(j), c(k) {}

    Point a, b, c;
};
```

This does use the "constructor delegation" feature you mentioned because that applies to constructors calling other constructors of the same class.  It uses initialization lists and class member initializers (`= 0`) to make the code more concise and idiomatic (by being able to use the `= default` declarations for the default constructors, rather than having to write them ourselves).

If you really wanted to use constructor delegation for `Point`, you'd write the default constructor like this instead:

```
Point() : Point(0, 0) {}
```

And then you wouldn't need the `= 0` for `x` and `y`.